# How to create curtain nav menu on mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, nav

This is my nav menu This is my nav menu This is my nav menu

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">
    <i class="fa fa-home" class="icon"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;HOME
  </a>
  <a href="#news">
    <i class="fa fa-universal-access"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;VENDORS
  </a>
  <a href="#contact">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;LOGIN
  </a>
  <a href="#about">
    <i class="fa fa-user-plus"> </i> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;REGISTER
  </a>
  <a href="#about">
    <i class="fa fa-briefcase"> </i> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;HOW IT WORKS
  </a>
  <a href="#about">
    <i class="fa fa-id-card"> </i> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;CONTACT US
  </a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

I tried this for mobile but it only collapses it,,doesn't give the curtain effect
I tried this for mobile but it only collapses it,,doesn't give the curtain effect
I tried this for mobile but it only collapses it,,doesn't give the curtain effect

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
.icon
{
    padding-left:20px;
}
```

Comment: Look at the examples in W3S: [How TO - Curtain Menu](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_curtain_menu.asp)

Comment: Please could you consolidate the two Snippets into one so that we can see it working?